# BLE Android Rotating 3D Objects Project - SensorTag 2650

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gyroscope, texas-instruments

A few days ago I started to develope a project on Android trying to use a SennsorTag 2650 Gyroscope data to rotate 3d Objects. I encountred some issues due to the data accuracy and I want to share with you my experience. It is a part of a VR bigger project that I would like to develope.
This is a demonstration video of my results:

[Andorid+SensorTag Rotating 3d Objects Project](https://youtu.be/WNUH1Zdl1qs)

In this app I can switch on receiving Gyroscope data from 2 different sources:  Samsung Galaxy s6 / SensorTag 2650

The problem is that SensorTag Gyro data are so inaccurate.

- I can register movement even when the sensor is motionless.
- Sometimes I register data on an axis which is not involved

I would like to know if is my SensorTag fault....maybe it could be broken.

Have you some pratical advices about it?

Thanks,

Federico

Comment: Did you filter the data at all? Have you tried the accelerometer data?

Comment: No, I didn't...and sincerly i have no idea on how to do it! How can I filter or cut data from gyroscope without deforming them or making them unreal?

Comment: You can filter a series of readings to smooth them. Simple way is to use the average of the last three readings (on each axis) as the smoothed reading. 'make them unreal' - you won't be making up data, just using a few actual unsmoothed data points to develop a slower-changing filtered data point. What is the actual problem with the data you are getting, not obvious (to me) in the video.

Comment: The accelerometer data may be more accurate (once the device isn't moving) than gyro because gravity has an absolute direction whereas gyros can drift.

Comment: Thank you barny..After searching I understand that I have to combine both Gyro and Accelerometer data to have a more accurate position..I'm studying about it but i'm a little be confuesed at the moment in tilt measuraments using accelerometer data. I'm trying to find the right formula...

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what is actually wrong with the data you are getting from the SensorTag gyro? Also if you can include links to info about combining gyro/accelerometer that is interesting to me, I'm trying to use accelerometer data from a Pi SenseHat and would like to improve it.